# Spring Boot MongoDB Repository null during unit test

Tags: java, mongodb, unit-testing, spring-boot, repository

I have been at this for a while but can't figure it out. The repo injects fine when running the app normal, but when trying to do a spring boot unit test it never injects. Here is the code:

```html
package com.g2p.g2prestservice.repositories;

        import com.g2p.g2prestservice.model.User;
        import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends MongoRepository<User, Integer> {


}
```

```html
package com.g2p.g2prestservice.repositories;

import com.g2p.g2prestservice.model.User;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class UserRepositoryTest {

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void testInsertUser() {
        User user = new User("fake@email.com", "fakePassword");

        userRepository.save(user);

        assertEquals(userRepository.count(), 1);
    }

}
```

I am essentially trying to follow this guide as example: https://springframework.guru/configuring-spring-boot-for-mongo/

Thank you all for solving what I am sure is a very elementary mistake.

EDIT: I THINK the problem is that the spring context isn't launching when I run the test class...

EDIT: Here is launcher class:

```html
package com.g2p.g2prestservice;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;

@SpringBootApplication
public class G2pRestServiceApplication {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(G2pRestServiceApplication.class, args);
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you used `@EnableMongoRepositories` on your launcher file?

Comment: Can you elaborate on that Harshit? I'm a spring-boot newbie. Where is the launcher file?

Comment: Your Application file with main method, where you start the Application, like this,
`public class Application {

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
 }
}`

Comment: Ahh, of course that's what you meant. It's been a long day for me. I did not have that annotation there, but adding it did not solve my problem. As I mentioned, mongodb works just fine when launching the app normal "mvn spring-boot:run" for example. It just doesn't work when running the unit test.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
@SpringBootTest(classes= {Application.class})
```

where Application.class is where you wrote you SpringApplication.run code.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
```

Comment: Added and still getting the null repo.

Comment: does your Application.class looks something like this?  -> 
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
 }
}

Comment: Hi dsncode, I added the Application class to the original post.